# How to authenticate to Outlook mail using Azure AD v2.0 in Java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure AD. I am looking for a programmatic way to fetch mails from MS Outlook. I am trying to use the Azure AD v2 authentication endpoint. When I tried to GET/POST to the url https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize from java  with the required parameters, I am getting a login page as the response instead of an expected code. How could I override this or is there something I missed.

Please advise.

Comment: If you want to authenticate a user, you need to show the user a web browser that goes to that URL. Otherwise, if you want app-only access, you'll need application permissions, and use `/token` instead of `/authorize`.

Comment: Thanks Junnas. I would like my java app to authenticate always with a single mail id (for eg: i will always use  abhi@hotmail.com to access a mailbox,say, abc@icon.com). If I go directly to /token, i need to supply the parameter code too, which I could get only from /authorize

Comment: Depends on which authentication flow you use. Authorization Code flow requires the code from /authorize. Client Credentials allows you to get an access token in the name of your app. You should probably check all the possible authentication scenarios for Azure AD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios

Comment: Without UI, you can only use client credentials flow. Other supported flow all needs UI to authorize first. Additional, AAD doesn't support you use Resource owner password credentials flow! So, I think you have to make a choice.